# Use KeyboardEvent.code to replace KeyboardEvent.keyCode, but it's empty

Tags: javascript, html

Because `keyCode` is deprecated, so I'd like to change it to `code`, but here I get nothing.

```
public async onKeyboardKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent): Promise<void> {
        debugger
        console.log("keyCode", event.keyCode);
        console.log("code", event.code);
        console.log("key", event.key);
}
```

I can get result from `event.keyCode`, from `event.key`, but there is nothing in `event.code`. And it shouldn't be a browser version problem. Chrome supports it from Chrome 51, and I've used `navigator.userAgent` to check, it's 68.

PS: it's a web page inside a C++ desktop client. (client opens a window and it redirects to my url)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the input device isn't a physical keyboard, but is instead a virtual keyboard or accessibility device, the returned value will be set by the browser to match as closely as possible to what would happen with a physical keyboard, to maximize compatibility between physical and virtual input devices.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code

Comment: unfortunately it's a very normal physical keyboard btw